# C: Ways to use scanf

Tags: c, input, io, scanf

Can I use `scanf(...)` as argument to a function ? 
Like this:

```
printInteger(scanf(....));
```

Can I use `scanf` to attribute the value that I read to some variable ?
Like this:

```
n = scanf(...);
```

p.s.: Here I'm explaining why I'm asking this.

This question can be a little weird I know, but I'm working in a project, which is developing a compiler that takes some language as input and then compile to C.

For example, this is my language, let's call 'stackoverflow' ;)

```
proc printInteger(integer k)
    integer i;
        begin
            for i = 1 to k do
                print i;
        end

proc main()
    integer n, i;
    boolean ok;
    begin
        printInteger(getInteger);
        n = getInteger;
        ok = true;
        while i < n do
            begin
                print i;
                i = i + 1;
            end
        if ok then print 1; else print 0;
    end
```

I won't get deeper in the language, but notice that `getInteger` means that I would like to do a `scanf(...)`, what I mean is, when appears `getInteger` I would like to compile as `scanf(...)`, so that's why I would like to know some ways to use `scanf(...)`.

Comment: If you were using C++ it would just be `in >> n` and all happen typesafe and automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I use scanf(...) as argument to a function ? Like this:
>
> printInteger(scanf(....));
>
> Can I use scanf to attribute the value that I read to some variable ? Like this:
>
> n = scanf(...);

You **can** use `scanf` as an argument to a function, but the real answer to both questions is no: `scanf` **doesn't** return any data scanned, it returns the *number* of items successfully scanned - or `EOF` if the end-of-input is reached before any successful scanning. You only get access to the items scanned using the pointers that you pass as `scanf` arguments to receive the values. So while you *can* pass `scanf` as an argument to a function, it won't do what you seem to want.

If you want to implement the `getInteger` operation in your language, in C, it's hard to make suggestions since only you know how this language/operation should work. Just using `scanf`, the implementation would look something like this:

```
int nextInt;
int numScanned = scanf("%d", &nextInt);

if (numScanned < 1)
    handleError();
return nextInt;
```

But if you're doing general parsing for your language, then using `scanf` is a bad idea: you'll soon run into problems with the limitations of `scanf`, and you're not going to be able to anticipate all of the input types unless your language is *really simple*, simpler than the example that you've included.

To do this properly, find a good [`lex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) library for C. This will prevent a lot of headaches. Otherwise, if you must do the lexing yourself, start looking over `fgets`, get a line at a time from your input, and do the tokenizing yourself.

Comment: but do you know any alternative to my cases ?

Comment: without additional library support or functions, no. From your examples you need a function that returns e.g. the next entered token as an `int`. In C, without additional libraries, you'll need to write this.

Comment: any idea what I should put as in place in `printInteger(getInteger); ` instead ?

Comment: @ValterHenrique: It depends on what you want the `printInteger()` function to do if there is no integer to read (the next character is a letter or punctuation symbol), or if there is no data left to read (EOF).  Generally, you will call a function to do the input and error check the result.  If there is no error, then you can call the `printInteger()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Can I use scanf(...) as an argument to a function like this?
>
> ```
> printInteger(scanf(....));
> ```

The answer to the first question is "Yes, but ...".

> Can I use scanf to attribute the value that I read to some variable like this?
>
> ```
> n = scanf(...);
> ```

The answer to the second is "No, because ...".

The "but" is mostly 'but it does not do what you expect so you would very seldom, if ever, do so'.

In the first example, `scanf()` returns either the (integer) number of successful conversions, or EOF if it reached EOF.  In no case does it return the value that it just read (not least because, in general, it reads multiple values and most of them are not integers).  So, if you want to print the number of values that was converted, you could use the `printInteger()` function to do so, but it is not what you'd normally want to do.

Similarly, in the second case, you can certainly assign the result of `scanf()` to an integer `n` as shown (and it is often sensible to do so if you're going to need to report an error).  However, that is not the value that was read (assuming you had a `%d` conversion specification); it is the number of successful conversions.